# Localization in JSF. The messages from a imported jar are always in english

Tags: java, jsf, jar, internationalization, locale

I have and java web application where the internationalization is working perfectly.
But I want to import another .jar, who has internationalization too, working perfectly when it's used in desktop applications.

When I put the jar inside the lib folder of java war file and run the webapp, all the webapp internationalization works perfectly, in exception of the messages inside this imported jar.

The imported jar is using the locale of the server, but how to proceed in a situation like these. I want both, jar an war use the browser locale. Do I need to configure some extra in faces-config.xml?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One should not switch the defaalt locale on a per user request basis. Maybe you have to patch the `Locale.getDefaultLocale()` using the servlet context or retranslate their messages:

Copy their bundles for your own translation.

Keep one bundle with root locale (""), with

```
key1=key1
key2=key2

# Now a message format:
key3=key3\u2622{0}\u2622{1}
```

It translates the key to itself, with added parameters possibly.

Comment: Could you send me a tutorial about this translation? How can I translate when a jar it's from a third part?

Comment: Reverse enginieering. If the jar returns strings to pass on; the above procedure would work (by unzipping the jar). If it is a component with its own text only AOP interceptors or other hacking might work. Don't they have a forum?

Comment: I'm not sure if I express all this problem well. Let me try again: If the browser request is in Germany, why the jar inside the lib folder don't throw messages in germany too like all the whole app? Is this the default behavior? jar inside lib folder always will use the server locale and not the browser locale? Seems logic to me but I would like to confirm it.

Comment: In JSF one can hold a locale, even set it: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale("eo");`. If the library is not made for use in JSF, you have to search their APIs for some way.